# Where to find a frequency doubler that works on signals between 5 and 500 KHz?

Tags: frequency, signal-processing

I've found many frequency doublers that work in the MHz range but having trouble finding any for KHz frequencies. I need to take a signal produced from some digital electronics and double the frequency of this signal. Where might I find such a device?

The signal I want to double the frequency of looks like so:
[image]

I have thus-far been using an FPGA to read in the signal, remove the DC offset and then squaring the value in order to frequency double it, but the DC offset varies significantly and results in the output signal being not a precise frequency doubling and occasionally outputting at the frequency rather than doubling it.

The power spectral density of this signal looks like so:

[image]

Comment: Any constraints on waveform or duty cycle of the output waveform? If not, search for "Peter Alfke Six Easy Pieces".

Comment: What you show is not a signal directly derived from a digital circuit. Do you have access to the actual digital signal? Is only one frequency present at any one time? What are the levels and impedances?

Comment: Yes, the signal is from an FPGA, I have access to the digital signal inside the FPGA. If everything is working ideally then there should be only 1 frequency, in any case, if there are other frequency components there they should be small in comparison to the primary signal.

Comment: I've added the power spectral density of this signal to my question.

Comment: Since you get this signal from an FPGA, it is not a device what you need but an **algorithm**. This makes it more of a signal processing question.

Comment: You can easily make a digital frequency doubler with diodes or XOR gate with time delay, but doubling produces all the sum and difference harmonics, so not possible with simple analog. One can consider complete PLL and filter solutions if you define the purpose.

Comment: Double what? No detailed Specs. So no Answers. 2x zero=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can easily do it with your FPGA, no extra hardware is needed.**

If you already have a working FPGA method for a fixed DC offset, you can allow the DC offset to be variable by using something called a "leaking integrator": From each sample s subtract a variable offset v. Modify the value of v for each sample by increasing v by one when s is positive and decreading v by one when s is negative. That way the value of v follows the changing DC offset and what remains after the subtraction is the AC component of the signal. Then you can square that signal.

[Edit] Lol, it's been so many years since I was in the university, I had to reassure myself that square of sine is in fact twice the frequency... which of course it is. :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gain up the signal to the volt level and then use an analog multiplier.  You'll have to take off the DC offset. (High pass filter.)  That would be one analog method.

Comment: Something similar can be done in the digital domain (on the FPGA) provided the FPGA is powerful enough and provided you have someone to help you making the function into the FPGA (I do not expect this to be trivial).

Answer (score 0):

You may use two edge trigered monoflops. Remove the DC offset, amplify to TTL level. One monoflop should be triggered by positive edges, the other by negative edges. The outputs of the monoflops are combined with an OR gate. The output pulse time for both monoflops should shorter then a quarter of the period of the 500 kHz. Of course you do not get a square wave signal for lower frequencies than 500 kHz. But you did not require a special waveform for the output. All this may be done with some TTL chips and an analog opamp.